# sql query finding the earliest date for each bussiness

Tags: sql

have written an SQL query that joins two tables- one containing businesses and the other containing the dates on which they were inspected. Businesses may be inspected 0, 1 or multiple times.

the database I am using can be found [here](https://relational.fit.cvut.cz/dataset/SFScores)

```
sql_query = """\
SELECT
MIN(ins.date) as min_date,
MAX(ins.date) as max_date
FROM businesses as res
INNER JOIN inspections as ins
ON res.business_id == ins.business_id
WHERE ins.Score NOT NULL
"""
```

This query gives the first date and late that any business was inspected, but I`d like to generate a table showing the first and last date *each* business was inspected.

I can't work out how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to group by the business id, so the min and max function will return the data for all the inspections of that business

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(ins.date) as min_date,
    MAX(ins.date) as max_date
FROM businesses as res
    INNER JOIN inspections as ins
ON res.business_id == ins.business_id
WHERE ins.Score NOT NULL group by ins.business_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `join` for the query that you have in your question:

```
SELECT ins.business_id, MIN(ins.date) as min_date,
       MAX(ins.date) as max_date
FROM inspections ins
WHERE ins.Score NOT NULL;
```

Well, you *would* need a `JOIN` if -- for instance -- there were rows in `inspections` that did not have a valid `business_id`.  But I am assuming the tables are properly structured.